# How to Convert a Text Format to customize Date format on SSAS with Visual Studio for displaying on tabular?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, data-analysis, business-intelligence

How to Convert a Text Format to customize Date format on SSAS with Visual Studio for displaying on tabular? E.g. from 3/01/2012 text format to 3 Jan 12? I cant seem to convert to this customize date format even with this function  Format([TableName],"dd-mmm-yy") into a new calculated column, as for date data this function works. Anyone please help!

Comment: SSAS is a SQL Server product. Why tag MySQL as well?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the original column into date type, then you could create a calculated column doing something like the following:

```
New Date Formatted := FORMAT(Data[DateColumn], "d mmm yy")
```

Comment: @StelloK The data[date column] is a way to covert data type? And the data is to replace date datatype?

Comment: @JackyHan the data[date column] is your date column I just gave it a generic name; the DAX I provided can be used to create a calculated column based on your current date field.